# Maximizing $(x-5)^2$ subject to $0 \leqslant x \leqslant 10$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization

I am working on a simple case of convex optimization. I modeled the system on paper and now am using Python the [RSOME](https://github.com/XiongPengNUS/rsome) library. I want to maximise $(x-5)^2$ (bounded between $0 \leqslant x \leqslant 10$) but the code keeps telling me that this is a nonconvex case. Does anyone know if it is nonconvex? a positive parabola is fundamentally convex no?

Here is my Python code:

```
import rsome as rso
import numpy as np
from rsome import ro
from rsome import dro
from rsome import E     
#from rsome import eco_solver as grb
from rsome import grb_solver as grb
model = dro.Model('test')            # create an RSOME model

x = model.dvar()



model.max(rso.square(x-5)) #working
#model.st(rso.square(x-5) <= 100)
#model.st(x <= 10)
#model.st(rso.square(x-5))


model.st(x= >= 0)
model.st(x <= 5)

model.solve(grb)

print(x.get())

user_value = x.get()
```

Here are the error messages:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-ffa94a01dc07> in <module>
     21 model.st((x-5) <= 5)
     22 
---> 23 model.solve(grb)
     24 
     25 print(x.get())

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/rsome/lp.py in __ge__(self, other)
   2935         elif isinstance(left, DecConvex):
   2936             if left.sign == -1:
-> 2937                 raise ValueError('Nonconvex constraints.')
   2938             return DecCvxConstr(left, left.event_adapt)
   2939         elif isinstance(left, DecPerspConvex):

ValueError: Nonconvex constraints.
```

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange! Quick tip: posting code snippets or error messages is a good way to receive quality answers on this website. For example, you said that the code is "telling" you something. Why not paste that stacktrace in your question?

Comment: convex functions go well with minimizing not maximizing

Comment: Without looking through the code, my first instinct would be to make sure that the code is trying to find the max, as opposed to the min of your input function.  Finding the min is probably more standard.

Comment: Maximizing a convex function over a compact interval is a nonconvex problem but it is solved by one of the endpoints of the interval.  In your case, both endpoints are solutions: Maximizing $(x-5)^2$ over $x \in [0, 10]$ has solution set $\{0, 10\}$ (which is a nonconvex set).  In contrast, the solution set to a convex problem is always a convex set.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I added the code I wrote. I am confused why I cannot use maximization with cases over such an interval. I get I should just try the end points. But why can I not test it as a convex problem? Why is it non convex?

Comment: Because you're maximizing it. If you were minimizing it, it would be convex. See the comment from @Michael.

Comment: Great! Ok thank you!